# Can HornetQ retrieve messages from mailbox?

Tags: jboss, jms, exchange-server, hornetq

I'd like to use HornetQ on JBoss to retrieve messages from Microsoft Exchange mailbox. Is it possible at all? If so, what should I look into? I've spent time on google but no luck so far. I'll be grateful for any hints/names etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should research a bit more. HornetQ is a MOM, Message Oriented Middleware:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware

it will use proprietary and public MOM protocols such as HornetQ core protocol, AMQP and Stomp.

Microsof Exchange is an e-mail server basically... you can't consume messages from an email server using a MOM solution which is meant to intercommunication between applications.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that coming, but just didn't want to accept it.